# How to get user id from Message.Entity?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Currently, I'm trying to fetch user IDs from `update.Message.Entities`, for work control items operations. Things is, I have mapped organization user IDs with Telegram user IDs. I have 2 variants:

- @username
- 1234567890

[Telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) stablishes this format for MarkDown mention: `[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)` and I can't use the username to mention a user.

So,

1. What's the right path to get user_id (`long`) value?.
2. Is there a way to mention user by `user_name`?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so first off, you'll have to gather the message entity referencing to the user, which I suppose you're already doing.
Let's say, for instance, that the user is mentioned at `index [1]` in `message.Entities` array, to gather user's id you have to do something like this:

```
User usr = message.Entities[1].User as User;
long id = usr.Id;
```

and there you go, you have the id.

Second of all, yes you can 'mention' a user by his 'first_name' but using a bit of a hack... here it is:

```
await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat, $"<a href=\"tg://user?id={usr.Id}\">{usr.FirstName}</a>", parseMode: Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ParseMode.Html);
```

and there you go!